# java get all values for a field in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i have java sample code that insert 2 basic documents

```
@Container
private final ElasticsearchContainer elasticContainer = DataApiElasticSearchContainer.getInstance();

HttpEntity<String> entity_post = new HttpEntity<>("{\"man_name\": \"Hello world!\"}", headers);
HttpEntity<String> entity_post2 = new HttpEntity<>("{\"man_name\": \"Hello world666!\"}", headers);
HttpEntity<String> entity_get = new HttpEntity<>("{\n" +
        "  \"aggs\": {\n" +
        "    \"genres\": {\n" +
        "      \"terms\": { \"field\": \"man_name\" } \n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}" +
        "}", headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response_post =
        restTemplate.exchange("http://" + elasticContainer.getHttpHostAddress() + "/bookindex/man_name",
                HttpMethod.POST, entity_post,String.class);
assertThat(response_post.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED);
ResponseEntity<String> response_post2 =
        restTemplate.exchange("http://" + elasticContainer.getHttpHostAddress() + "/bookindex/man_name",
                HttpMethod.POST, entity_post2,String.class);
assertThat(response_post2.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED);
ResponseEntity<String> response =
        restTemplate.exchange("http://" + elasticContainer.getHttpHostAddress() + "/bookindex/_search",
                HttpMethod.GET, entity_get, String.class);
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

But i have this output from my get body

```
{"took":36,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

i want list of man_name values like this : ["Hello world!", "Hello world666!"]

Answer (score 0):

If I get you question right, There is nothing wrong with your code and every time you execute the code you will receive the log that your two documents ingested successfully in one shard but if you want to get the list of your ingested documents as you may know you need to add query Api such below at the end of your http request . In this manner you will receive the list of your documents.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/yourindexname/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "query": {"match_all": {}}}'
```